# LSTM multiple features prediction : shape to give to data (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

After long research, I was unable to find an answer for this question.

My data is a series of items, each having a number of features. The data is in this form:
[image: Data schema]

I want to guess the features of the n+1 element.
Should the network have a particular number of nodes? What should be the shape of the data fed into the LSTM Tensorflow network and its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the input and output sizes, you have defined them yourself in the picture: you want to predict a vector of length `num_features` (4 in your picture) from an input matrix of shape `(N, num_features)` where `N` is the number of samples to use for one prediction.

In tensorflow, the placeholders usually have the shape `(batch_size, number_of_steps, number_of_features)`. For you, they could look like this

```
input_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, None, num_features), dtype=..., name='inputs')
target_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, num_features), dtype=..., name='targets')
```

in case you don't want to predefine `N` - then you need to have a fixed batch size. Otherwise you could also have

```
input_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, N, num_features), dtype=..., name='inputs')
target_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, num_features), dtype=..., name='targets')
```

in which `N` would be fixed and your batch size variable. (You cannot have both variable.)

---

As for your network size, you need to experiment yourself: it is impossible to make an a priori judgement on the require number of nodes, layers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still unsure at what is "batch_size" in this example and how it should be defined.

Comment: Usually you don't just pass one input + label to the network at a time for training, but multiple inputs + labels. This is called learning with minibatches, and `batch_size` is the number of examples per network execution.